Top of the World
This is part 61 of the puzzle series Around the World in Many Days. Each part is solvable on its own.

Dear Puzzling,
Today I have travelled to admire another massive mountain peak from a very safe distance. This one is considered a sacred place by the locals here and, despite not being a household name, holds a special distinction among the world’s mountains. Can you guess where I am?
Love, Gladys.

Solve on Penpa+
Across
1. A famous one was named after Warsaw
5. Angle, curve
9. A retailer from the Netherlands
13. Bustle, commotion
14. Comedic partner of Jake
15. Cooked food in the form of a creamy, thick paste or liquid
17. Downtown St. Petersburg lies on its bank
18. Framework for improvisation in Indian music
19. Garfield's middle name?
20. General term for a small integrated circuit in electronics
23. Glamorous ride
24. Has a slant towards one side
25. Inhabitants
27. International airport close to the Great Barrier Reef
29. Joined together (e.g. two ropes)
30. —, known also as egg cells
31. Largest French overseas region
32. (unclued)
39. Make possible
40. Mesozoic or Paleozoic, for example
41. Nonsense
43. Over time, becomes mature (e.g. fruit)
46. Oxygen provider, for aquarium fish
47. Palestine's ruler in the first century BC
48. Person from ancient Scotland
49. Relating to established figurative expressions
52. Seat of government of an African nation
54. Slothful, averse to work
55. Take off the outer covering of
57. The main branch of Islam in Saudi Arabia
58. To desire, require
59. Tract of land, not very large, surrounded by water on all sides
60. — up, started a game of golf
61. Very doable
62. Winner of three Grammies for jazz and blues, — James
Down
1. Absolutely humiliate, in gamer terms
2. A sound of someone clearing their throat
3. At war, a person not taking part in fighting
4. Bullet treated with a substance to make it leave a visible trail in the dark
5. Byron, Munchausen and Richthofen, for example
6. Coder's alternative to vi
7. Coming soon, poetically
8. Downspout
9. French-speaking Belgian town known for its mineral baths
10. Greedy taxman of ancient times
11. Hit it big
12. Increased the size of (47 down), using a specialised tool
16. Individuals who like Fall Out Boy?
21. Jogged
22. Koror is its largest city
26. Little piece of a comb or a fork
27. Machine part
28. Ms Gardner of old Hollywood
29. Noticeably grumpy and ill-tempered
31. Outer garment worn by Shakespeare's Shylock
33. Photographic film commonly contains this jelly-like substance
34. Problem that may be Gordian
35. Pyramid puzzle game, Towers of —
36. Ragged, to an extreme
37. Receptacle for ashes
38. Salvadoran's more or most
41. Seat of government of an Asian nation
42. Secret, mysterious
43. Substance used to cure a disease
44. Tin Pan Alley lyricist Gershwin
45. Type of baked dish with meat
46. Uber and Instagram, say
47. Usually, a golf course consists of 18 —
50. Vague notion
51. Welshman or Breton, say
53. Wembley concert in 1985, Live —
56. Woodless grassy field

Gladys will return in Restricted.

Nice touch alphabetizing the clues.

@caPNCApn Thanks! I almost gave it up after running into a dead end, but I'm glad I stuck with it :)

Gladys is at:

 GANGKHAR PUENSUM

Here is the completed grid:

 

Clues

 





Spot on! Nice job.

Nice puzzle. Just to add, coming from a newcomers standpoint to puzzles I have found almost every puzzle you posted to be accessible bar the cryptic crosswords. So thanks!

Thanks for that!!
